# And suddenly, all my controls aren't declared! (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, controls

This is strange. Everything worked great this morning on my ASP project.

Suddenly, I have 48 errors. Similar to the following:

```
Name 'pnlVars' is not declared
'txtPolicyNo' is not a member of 'LetterWriterASP.UW'
```

Seems every control I reference is now no longer declared or not a member of my project.

I checked the page, the controls are all there with the same names & IDs.

What happened? .NET glitch?

Comment: this is a known bug with the compiler

Comment: @I__: Can you point me to a page that indicates this "bug" is "known"? If it *is* a bug, it's almost certainly related to the IDE, not the compiler.

Comment: @Cody, it is obviously a bug. It does hang the compiler (can't build as a result). IDE, precompiler, who knows. But I'll bet a few thousand people *do* know about this bug simply from direct experience. I am one.

Comment: The fact that the compiler can't build the project doesn't mean it's a bug with the compiler. If you tell the compiler to build nonsense code, it isn't going to work either. That's not the compiler's fault. There's no "precompiler" in VB.NET, and it definitely matters whether the IDE or the compiler is at fault. I wasn't criticizing your question; my comment was a response to I__'s assertion. One left quite unsubstantiated and, I'm afraid, extremely misleading.

Comment: The code worked just fine, before this. I agree with you, it's probably not the compiler. But it is definitely a bug, most likely with the IDE, which does execute some sort of pre-compile activity which would explain why I can't build code which built just fine an hour ago. In any case, I would like to work the problem here and ask why my controls appear on my aspx page but suddenly cannot be referenced in my VB code?

Comment: If you look at the (filename).aspx.designer.vb files, you'll see that they are now empty, which is what is causing your asp controls to be invisible to the code behind. My solution that worked for me is listed as an answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it also helps to make sure, when you add a copied aspx page to your solution, to double-check the CodeBehind page tag and make sure it's not pointing to any other pages in your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try closing your Visual Studio and re-opening again.  It happens to me from time to time and restart seems to always do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen before, I just close and reopen visual studio and all is well.

Comment: Tried again, will restart the computer.

Comment: Restarted the computer and STILL have the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Guys, thanks for the help. Restarting VS2008 didn't quite work, but I'll list the steps I took which eliminated the errors:

```
1) Restarted VS
2) Restarted Windows
3) Opened VS project
4) Selected one of the "erroneous" controls on the aspx page
5) CTRL + X (cut)
6) CTRL + V (paste in same place)
7) Remaining errors mysteriously vanished
8) Wait two days to select this as the answer
```

Thanks again for your help!

-Jason

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to me. Changing design elements, before or after deleting and creating a new designer.vb page did not work.

Changing the name of the main .aspx pages that were giving me problems (which causes the .vb and designer.vb pages to automatically get renamed), and then changing it back forced Visual Studio (2012 for me just now) to regenerate the designer files when it went to update the name.